# Filter custom in selectOneListbox or SelectOneMenu to ignore accents or special characters

Tags: javascript, primefaces

How to filter in the search field of these Primefaces components so that they ignore special characters such as accents.

[image: example custom filter]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To customize the filter you have to define the filterMatchMode attribute as "custom" and use the filterFunction = "myFilter" attribute where the javascript function is defined, as defined in the [Primefaces documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_6_2.pdf) (466 or 470).

In this case I will customize the filter to ignore accents and special characters and that is contained (same as filterMatchMode="contains")

file.xhtml

```
<p:selectOneListbox filter="true" filterMatchMode="custom" filterFunction="contains" value="#{controllerBean.id}">  
        <f:selectItems value="#{controllerBean.list}" var="item" itemLabel="#{item.value}" itemValue="#{item.id}" />
</p:selectOneListbox>
```

file.js

```
 function contains(itemLabel, filterValue) {

    return itemLabel.includes(filterValue) || specialCharacters(itemLabel).includes(filterValue);

}

function specialCharacters(input){

           var c=input.toLowerCase();
           c = c.replace(new RegExp("\\s", 'g'),"");
           c = c.replace(new RegExp("[àáâãäå]", 'g'),"a");
           c = c.replace(new RegExp("æ", 'g'),"ae");
           c = c.replace(new RegExp("ç", 'g'),"c");
           c = c.replace(new RegExp("[èéêë]", 'g'),"e");
           c = c.replace(new RegExp("[ìíîï]", 'g'),"i");                           
           c = c.replace(new RegExp("[òóôõö]", 'g'),"o");
           c = c.replace(new RegExp("œ", 'g'),"oe");
           c = c.replace(new RegExp("[ùúûü]", 'g'),"u");
           c = c.replace(new RegExp("[ýÿ]", 'g'),"y");
           return c;
}
```

Comment: What will happen if you do search using special characters?

Comment: In my case it is not necessary, for that it would be necessary to compare if each filter character is special and not replace the itemLabel

Comment: I would say `return itemLabel.includes(filterValue) || specialCharacters(itemLabel).includes(filterValue);`

Comment: that's right, it's more complete, thank you, i edit the answer and i add it, greetings!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not correct, the correct code is:

```
return itemLabel.includes(filterValue) || specialCharacters(itemLabel).includes(specialCharacters(filterValue));
```

Comment: Thank you, if you want to obtain items without an accent searched in the filter with an accent then it would be as you indicate

In fact, the first part of the comparison would be left over, only with this it would be worth:
'return specialCharacters(itemLabel).includes(specialCharacters(filterValue));'

Anyway, this would be a comment because is not the complete solution, just a suggestion.

Comment: True, that would be more appropriate